# laravel queue jobs table not attempting for sending email in server

Tags: laravel, queue

Locally queues jobs table works fine and sending mail to users but in server queues storing the data in jobs table but not sending the queues emails to users.

Comment: have you run 'php artisan queue:work' on your project root folder?

Comment: i have tested locally it works fine but it not working in server

Comment: check your failed_jobs table or just like @SurenderSinghRawat suggests you should be executing your queues with php artisan queue:work --queue=etc

Comment: check connection to redis